# Can't get the right result when using re.findall function on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to match the right string with regular expressions, but I can't.

```
import re
str = "<meta apple <meta" \
  "we go<meta" \
  "goto mac <meta td yiyang ziyou" \
  "net<meta aaask zoie where to go?" \
  "<meta " \
  "buy mac"
r = re.findall("<meta(?!.*<meta).*mac", str, re.S)
```

I think there will be matched two strings, one is `<meta goto mac`, another is `<meta buy mac`, but I just got the last. Why? I use PyCharm 5.0.3, the version of python is 3.5.1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have a negative look-ahead operator `(?!.*<meta)` which means that for any match, there must *not* be a `<meta` later in the string.

For this reason, only your last `<meta` string is matched, because only it can satisfy this criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer says the reason of why you got only the last match and note that there isn't a newline character in your input string and you don't need to add `re.S` modifier. `<meta(?!.*<meta)` negative lookahead asserts that there wouldn't be a string `<meta` exists next to `<meta`, so this occurs only on the last.

In-order to get the result, your regex must be

```
<meta(?:(?!<meta).)*?mac
```

*Example:*

```
>>> s = "<meta apple <meta" \
  "we go<meta" \
  "goto mac <meta td yiyang ziyou" \
  "net<meta aaask zoie where to go?" \
  "<meta " \
  "buy mac"
>>> s
'<meta apple <metawe go<metagoto mac <meta td yiyang ziyounet<meta aaask zoie where to go?<meta buy mac'
>>> re.findall(r'<meta(?:(?!<meta).)*?mac', s)
['<metagoto mac', '<meta buy mac']
```

Comment: How does the `(negative-lookahead)*` work? Checks that negative look-ahead for each position up until `mac`? Also why doesn't it work without the `.`?

Comment: @MartinKonecny it would check for the character going to be matched would not be the starting character of `<meta`. If yes, then only the following character got matched. Likewise it checks for each following character.

Answer (score 0):

The .* coupling in regular expressions is a useful, powerful tool but it is also very dangerous. you might want to make your regular expression a little bit more specific sometimes. The specific details on why was answered in the other posts. but if you are actually trying to look for a solution to match the items you seek here is the regular expression for it:

```
import re

string = "<meta apple <meta" \
"we go<meta" \
"goto mac <meta td yiyang ziyou" \
"net<meta aaask zoie where to go?" \
"<meta " \
"buy mac"

print re.findall('(<meta[\w\s]*mac)',string,re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Amazing! the regex is so simple, but how can it find the correct answer not `<meta apple <metawe go<metagoto mac` and `<meta td yiyang ziyounet<meta aaask zoie where to go?<meta buy mac` ?

Comment: explaining regular expressions is almost as hard as making them but I will try. You will need to copy my comment and put it in a word document or notepad and space it out.
"<meta---[\w\s]*-----mac" 
1. '<meta' is a literal match
2. '[\w\s]*' means \w OR \s repeat infinite
  ' \w' means any letter (A-Z a-z) any number (0-9) and the underscore character(_) 
the \s means any space \t \s \n etc
3.''mac" is a literal
When you put the whole statement together it means: find <meta with as many [A-Za-z0-9_] characters and or spaces in front and ends with mac

Comment: it just wont match the symbol < which my regular expression banks on